# Haskell Interactive mode - incorrect parsing of crammed code

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting, parsing

When using list comprehension without white spaces, all text after vertical bar turns grey.  `[x|` is treated like header of here-document - grey color spans for the rest of the buffer, unless sequence `|]` is present, which AFAIK is meaningless in Haskell. Also, I'm still on Debian Buster with vanilla Emacs 26.1, so this issue might be not present in newer versions. I know I could just use spaces, but is there any other fix?

For example, code snippet:

```
ls = [a| a<-[0..10]] ++ [1, 2, 3, 4]
ls1 = "xyz" ++ [b | b<-"string"] ++ [c | c <- "string" ]
-- comm|]ent highlighted as Code
-- properly coloured comment
```

Is rendered as:

[image]